# JavaScript CSV Reading Row and Columns and store in a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple requirement but not able to figure out as to how to do it.
Below Javascript code reads a CSV file and creates a HTML table. My CSV has following data in it:

```
Type, Item, Value, Dec, Figure
SUM,ThisItem,ThisValue,2,4
SUM,ThisItem1,ThisValue1,4,5
RCT,ThisItem1,ThisValue1,6,7
```

How can I insert a code or a line in below code that would help me store "Type" column value in a variable, "Item" column value in a variable and so on. For example, if Type=="SUM" then take some action (for example send data or complete row to table). I tried several times by adding some logic but to no avail.

```
function Upload() {
const columns = [0,1,2,3,4] // represents allowed column 1 and 3 in index form

var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { var cells = rows[i].split(","); if (cells.length > 1) {
                    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                        // ignore columns that are not allowed
                        if (!columns.includes(j)) {
                          continue
                        }

                        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                        cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
                    }
                }
            }
            var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
            dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
            dvCSV.appendChild(table);
        }
        reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
    } else {
        alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
} else {
    alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
}
```

}

Comment: `cells[j]` is the textual data coming from the CSV file? Example: `Type, Item, Value, Dec, Figure`?

Comment: yup, figured. Thanks.var rc = cells[j];
                            if (rc == "SUMMARY") {
                               var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                               cell.innerHTML = cells[j];                            
                               alert(rc);
                            }

Comment: So you got it figured out then yes?

Comment: yes, Thanks for your help. Can there be a simple solution? For example, cells[j] gives me all values. I would like to store "Type" value in a separate variable and then "Item" value in a separate variable.

Comment: For example, if "Type" == "SUMMARY" then complete row from CSV should go to a table and if "Type == "THIS" then complete row should go to another table.

Comment: and how do I accept your answer!

Comment: figure this too! var newcell = cells[0];
                        alert(newcell);
                        
                        if (newcell == "SUMMARY") {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cells[j]` is your textual content from the CSV file, use the conditional on each iteration to check if there is a match on the value you are looking for, if there is a match, then define your variable and complete your row.